# Java Extract unique columns from 2d array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, arff

I'm trying to create an .arff writer in java. The code below is the code used.
The dataset contains categorical values, which is denoted by a * in the header.

The header is seperate from the data portion. 
First I extract the columnID's of all the categorical columns. I now need help in extracting the unique values for each categorical column.

```js
public void datatoARFF(String nameARFF, int sizeFeatureSubset, datasetRead ob, String featureNames, int[] subsets) {
    PrintWriter writer = null;
    try {
        double[][] secsData = ob.getSecSet();
        ArrayList<String> currentCatSubs = new ArrayList<String>();
        //this method will create the arff file from the datafile stored for the feature subset.
        // Create new .csv file and store in SUBMIT folder
        File file = new File(nameARFF);
        writer = new PrintWriter(file);

        // Writes the Header
        writer.print("@relation '" + nameARFF + "'");
        writer.println();

        // Load featurenames and subsets into arrays.
        featureNames = featureNames.replaceAll(" ", "");
        featureNames = featureNames.replaceAll(".*\\{|\\}.*", "");
        String[] featureNamesArr = featureNames.split(",", -1);

        // Identifies the categorical values column ids as currentCatSubs
        for (int featureR = 0; featureR < sizeFeatureSubset; featureR++) {
            if (featCat(featureNamesArr[featureR], '*') != true) {
                //do nothing
            } else {
                //add to arraylist if categorical
                currentCatSubs.add(Integer.toString(featureR));
            }
        }
        currentCatSubs.add(Integer.toString(sizeFeatureSubset));

        // ******** NEED HELP HERE TO NOW EXTRACT ALL DISTINC VALUES FROM THE COLUMNS IDENTIFIED IN CURRENTCATSUBS AND THEN WRITE THEM BELOW. ********

        // Writes header with categorical values
        for (int feats = 0; feats < sizeFeatureSubset; feats++) {
            if (featCat(featureNamesArr[feats], '*') != true) {
                writer.println("@attribute '" + featureNamesArr[feats] + "' UNIQUE CATEGORIES FOR FEATURE");
            } else {
                writer.println("@attribute '" + featureNamesArr[feats] + "' real");
                currentCatSubs.add(Integer.toString(feats));
            }
        }
        // Writes the data into file
        writer.println("@attribute 'catClass' {0,1}");
        writer.println("@data");

        for (int row = 0; row < secsData.length; row++) {

            for (int col = 0; col < secsData[row].length; col++) {

                if (currentCatSubs.contains(Integer.toString(col))) {

                    writer.print((int) secsData[row][col]);
                } else {

                    writer.print(secsData[row][col]);
                }

                if (col < secsData[row].length - 1) writer.print(",");
            }

            writer.println();
        }
        writer.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(WekaFormatter.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } finally {
        writer.close();
    }
}

//Method to identify if feature is categorical or not based on * in name.
public boolean featCat(String str, char chr) {
    return str.indexOf(chr) != -1;
}
```

Comment: Okay, and what is your specific question?

Comment: Well if you've read it I now need help in extracting the unique values for each categorical column.

Then in the code itself, I've also shown where I require help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to preserve the order and get the unique values, you can use also use with Java 8 or 9. My suggestion would be in your code to make the content of `featureNamesArr` unique using this line of code:

```
List<String> featureNamesDistinct = Stream.of(featureNamesArr).distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

to get the distinct values for the feature names.

Then you will need to iterate through the distinct array instead of `featureNamesArr`:

```
// Identifies the categorical values column ids as currentCatSubs
for (int featureR = 0; featureR < sizeFeatureSubset && featureR < featureNamesDistinct.size(); featureR++) {
    if (featCat(featureNamesDistinct.get(featureR), '*')) {
        //add to arraylist if categorical
        currentCatSubs.add(Integer.toString(featureR));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, to explain currentCatSubs contains the column ID's of the columns which needs to be distinct. The data is stored in secsData a 2d array.

Answer (score -1):

> > First I extract the columnID's of all the categorical columns. I now need help in extracting the unique values for each categorical column.

When u use keyword unique value, u can use HashSet.
reference : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_hashset_class.htm

If u don't have memory problem, u can create HashSets to map each categorical column.

Like Code

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class ExtractUniqueValue {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int test[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 9 };// 9 appears twice
        ArrayList<String> currentCatSubs = new ArrayList<String>();
        Map<String, Set> HashSets = new HashMap<String, Set>();
        for (int i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
            if (test[i] < 5) {
                // do nothing
            } else {
                // add to arraylist if categorical
                currentCatSubs.add(Integer.toString(test[i]));
                if (HashSets.get(Integer.toString(test[i])) == null) {
                    HashSets.put(Integer.toString(test[i]), new HashSet());
                }
                Set hs = HashSets.get(Integer.toString(test[i]));
                hs.add(Integer.toString(test[i]));//because hashset will not add repeat value, u will get unique value.
            }
        }

        for (String key : HashSets.keySet()) {
            System.out.println("key=" + key);
            Set hs = HashSets.get(key);
            System.out.println("unique values=" + hs);
        }

    }
}
```

Output is

```
key=5
unique values=[5]
key=6
unique values=[6]
key=7
unique values=[7]
key=8
unique values=[8]
key=9
unique values=[9] // 9 only appears once
```

Comment: Thank you, so I'll loop through the featureSubsets array first then loop through the rows for each column.

Comment: @user2459813 did it help u solve your question? If not, has any question?